# python selenium chrome webdriver giving me data; page

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I've been working with the following code, trying to introduce myself to selenium. When it runs, the chrome browser opens, but the page is blank, with no source code a far as I can tell, and 'data;' in the address bar. Any information on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service_args = ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'])

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
browser.get(url)
```

I have also tried it without the service_args and tried it specifying the driver path and both, but get the same result each time

Comment: Works for me. What OS are you using?

Comment: Does this happen for different URLs?

Comment: I've tried google and bing. I'm on windows 10

Comment: You need to update the Selenium libs, drivers, and make sure that the browser is up-to-date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most possibility is your browser not compatible with the webdriver.  Please confirm your browser version and webdriver version.

My chrome version is 60 and chromerdriver is chromedriver_2.30.exe

You can find compatible version from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Comment: Thank you! I was using chrome version 60 and chromedriver_2.9. I went down to 2.3 and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Update the `chromedriver` and `Chrome` Browser, sometime I also faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error as such in your code. Though the documentation for `service_args` is missing in the [**`Selenium-Python` API Docs**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) as well as in the [**`ChromeDriver` Getting started Doc**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started). But [0096850](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-selenium/commit/00968505a130c7a3571c4504bddae43f1d9b1a59) clearly suggests `service_args` is implemented.

The `service_args` works well at my end. Hence I suspect there is a mismatch between `Selenium` version, `chromedriver` version and `Chrome` version we are using. First and foremost, we have to ensure that our `Selenium` version, `chromedriver` version and `Chrome` version are compatible. You can find the compatibility information on the [`Downloads`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) page of [**`ChromeDriver`**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) individually for each releases.

The [**`Downloads`**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) page clearly mentions:

> **`Latest Release: ChromeDriver 2.32 Supports Chrome v59-61`**

Additionally, you may be required to pass the argument `executable_path` to mention the absolute path of the `chromedriver` binary as follows:

> **`Windows 8 based code`**:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe', service_args = ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'])

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
browser.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem,but I solved it by updating my webdriver
Update your webdriver of chrome ,here is the link https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Codeception, start the test with :

`$I->amOnPage('/');`

Answer (score -1):

simply add this argument to selenium options (google how add options on solenium python to how to add options argument)

```
 options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9225")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.