# Chromedriver do not open a new session, it opens a new tab in a existing session

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code is running ok on some PCs, but there's one that it do not open a new private session, in this particular case, it loads the current chrome profile, in the same window that already is opened.
I tried looking on some stackoverflow questions to see if that happened to anybody else, but without success. Tried looking on this command line list "https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/" to see if something can help but I have no clue on how to make it work.
Even when there's no session opened, it loads the default user profile and nothing happens.
Selenium, chrome and chromedriver are up to date and with matching versions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException as NSEE

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Disable antivirus.

Comment: I thought of that, but you can imagine a way that the code would work without the need of external human interferences?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you add the config file used on that machine to the question?
It should be in `~/.config/google-chrome/`
Also, what happens when you run chrome from the command line?

Comment: I'm sorry @JamesBurgess, I just changed browser to firefox to avoid errors and it's working fine, I also can't get the config file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly pass the incognito flag to chrome before you instantiate the webdriver.

```
 chrome_options.add_argument('-incognito')
```

I suspect this is only happening on machines that are already signed in on chrome.

Comment: Actually another machines were signed in, but it doesn't happen. I tried in another 3 machines, and only one of then had this issue.

Comment: This discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile) explains how chromes login behaviour works. (always logs in as last user unless the `--profile-directory=<user>` flag is passed in.)

Comment: what gives e the creeps is that it doesn't happened before in any other machine, it was working fine even in logged in chromes till this particular issue happened.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but it didn't work too.